# Why do my if condition is not executing as expected in Django template?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

**what i am supposed to do?**

Okay, so I have a registration form and I want to verify if django `message == "password not strong enough"` and if this condition is true then execute this HTML code snippet

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" style="margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 13px; margin-top: 0;" role="alert">
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0rem; text-align: center;">
    Your password is not strong enough. New passwords must:
    <li>Be at least minimum eight to maximum 16 characters long.</li>
    <li>Contain one or more numbers.</li>
    <li>With at least one small and one capital letter.</li>
    <li>Include at least one special character like: [@#(/)+]</li>
</p>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
```

and if the above code doesn't execute then show a message coming from my Django views, which is written as follows

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" style="margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 13px; margin-top: 0;" role="alert">
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0rem; text-align: center;" {% if message.tags %} {% endif %}>
    {{ message }}
</p>

<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

**message conditions from `views.py file`**

```
if username_exists:
    messages.warning(request, "Username is not available")

if email_exists:
    messages.warning(request, "Email id is already registered")

if not pass_match:
    messages.warning(request, "Grr.. password does not match")

if not complex_pass(password):
    # complex_pass is a function which returns
    #  Boolean value either user entered password is complex or not

    messages.warning(request, "password not strong enough")
```

**The problem is with my if-else condition in my `Django template`**

The time when *condition*: `message == "password not strong enough"` is `True`, I am expecting to render a different HTML code snipped instead of showing `"password not strong enough"` but in my case, It is only rendering django message instead of the HTML code snippet.

**Here is the complete HTML code with `if-else` condition**

```
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if message == "password not strong enough" %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" style="margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 13px; margin-top: 0;" role="alert">
            <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0rem; text-align: center;">
                Your password is not strong enough. New passwords must:
                <li>Be at least minimum eight to maximum 16 characters long.</li>
                <li>Contain one or more numbers.</li>
                <li>With at least one small and one capital letter.</li>
                <li>Include at least one special character like: [@#(/)+]</li>
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>

    {% else %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" style="margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 13px; margin-top: 0;" role="alert">
            <p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0rem; text-align: center;" {% if message.tags %} {% endif %}>
                {{ message }}
            </p>

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

**This is what i can see in my browser**

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to handle this via messages? I would handle it in the password view form processing. In a CBV, inside form_valid, check for an adequate password and if not then `form.add_error('password', 'This is what's wrong with your password`). Then, `return self.form_invalid(form)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
messages.warning(request, "password not strong enough")
```

To that:

```
messages.warning(request, '''<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0rem; text-align: center;">
            Your password is not strong enough. New passwords must:
            <li>Be at least minimum eight to maximum 16 characters long.</li>
            <li>Contain one or more numbers.</li>
            <li>With at least one small and one capital letter.</li>
            <li>Include at least one special character like: [@#(/)+]</li>
            </p>''', extra_tags='safe')
```

Then change your `{{ message }}` to that:

```
{% if 'safe' in message.tags %}{{ message|safe }}{% else %}{{ message }}{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't check `message` against a string with `==` because it isn't a string itself.
If you load the message in the view and then print the type like:

```
messages.info(request, "password not strong enough")
storage = messages.get_messages(request)
for message in storage:
    print(type(message))
```

it'll print:
`<class 'django.contrib.messages.storage.base.Message'>`
So it isn't a string.
But simply casting it to a string like so: `if str(message) == "password not strong enough":` will work.

Obviously we want this to work in a template, and for that you can use the built-in filter `stringformat`.
So simply replace your if statement in your html template with this:

```
{% if message|stringformat:"s" == "password not strong enough" %}
```